# Can Visual Studio Code edit online websites?

Tags: web, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to use Visual Studio Code to edit pages on online websites? The pages I want to edit are static web pages. I'm wondering if Code can be used to edit them or if the only way it can be done is to edit the pages offline, then publish to the web server?

Comment: If you open the actual web page files in visual studio, I think you could edit the web page files in real time.  You may need to have visual studio running on the server that hosts the website

Comment: Thank you, Anthony.